# The import org.junit.jupiter cannot be resolved

Tags: java, visual-studio, gradle, intellij-idea, junit

Hey its the first time i use JUnit with Java and i'm not sure how to set it up inside Visual studio Code. I tried to put Junit-4.13.jar inside my a lib file in the root directory but nothing changed. any ideas? I am on MacOS.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213204/discussion-on-question-by-hazel-the-import-org-junit-jupiter-cannot-be-resolved).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were 2 main issues with this configuration:

- JUnit 4 dependency jar was used while in the source code imports from JUnit 5 API were used
- Tests resided in the same location as sources, while the dependencies defined via Gradle/Maven for tests limit the scope to `src/test/java` roots.

In a non-Gradle project the issue was fixed by adding the proper JUnit 5 dependencies to the module.

In the Gradle project the issue was fixed by moving the test class from `src/main/java` to `src/test/java`.

Sample Gradle project [is available on GitHub](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/tree/r5.6.2/junit5-jupiter-starter-gradle).

More details about using JUnit 5 can be found [in the official documentation](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-getting-started-example-projects).